# nodeJS upload issue proxy error 502 with PM2

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, pm2

I have an express nodeJS application that uploads and XLSX file and displays it content. The code in app.js is as following :

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var app = express()
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
//Upload XLSX file
app.post('/upload', upload.single('xlsx_file'), function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.file === undefined) {
        console.log("Error");
    } else {
        var mimetype = req.file["mimetype"];
        if (mimetype === "application/vnd.ms-excel.12" || mimetype === "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") {
            var path = req.file["path"];
            readXLSX(path, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Only Excel (2007) xslx files are allowed!</strong></p>");
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using PM2 advanced process manager to run my application for ever, when I do `pm2 start all` and try to upload a file I get :

Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /upload.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Additionally, a 502 Bad Gateway error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

when I run the app in debug mode with `DEBUG=myapp:* npm start`  the upload works fine.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: can you tell how you solved this?

Comment: I have the same issue